# Define variable by elements class even not displayed on current page

Tags: ruby, selenium

I'm using Ruby and Selenium to get some data from a page. I want to define variable with `driver.find_element`, but element is not currently visible on page.

```
next = driver.find_element(:class, 'right')
```

It returns `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError`

It works fine when element is present.
Any solutions?
Thank you!

Comment: why don't you try `ImplicitWait` and `ExplicitWaits`

Comment: same problem when i try with if driver.find_element(:class, 'right').displayed?

Comment: You can put waits.

Comment: I'm new with ruby, need some time to figured out usage of parameters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium works by executing Javascript commands. By using find_element it will search for the element on the DOM. If it cannot find it you will get the error you are getting. After all if an element is not on the DOM it cannot be found.

The real question is why do you want too find an element that is not currently present on the DOM? You can't do anything with somehing that doesn't exist.

All I could think of is that the element becomes present after the DOM has been loaded due to Javascript not being fully executed yet. If that is the case you can use a WebDriver::Wait to try and find the element for a certain amount of time.

A small example:

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10) # seconds
begin
  element = wait.until { driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element") }
ensure
  driver.quit
end
```

Edit to include try-catch example:

```
begin
    next = driver.find_element(:class, 'right')
    # Code for when element is found here
rescue NoSuchElementError
    # Code for when element is not found here
end
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but in my case, i have about 50 different pages, on current page the element isn't present. My goal is to verify, if that element exists on this page, do something, if doesn't exists do else. I'm not sure if i'm getting it right... thanks

Comment: @mihalp Ok so if I understand correctly you want to find out wether an element exists on the page or not. This can easily be achieved because of the exception you are getting. All you need to do place a try-catch block around the find_element() and catch the NoSuchElementError. When it gets thrown you know the element is not on this page.

Comment: Got it! done with begin and rescue. Works perfect. Thanks!